# Error in broadcast receiver when sending sms

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm calling this method when send button is clicked I'm getting this error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered:

and the error is showing when unregistering the broadcast receiver at `unregisterReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {}`

```
private void sendSMS(String edittextSmsNumber, String msg) {

    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /* base64msgString = Base64.encodeToString(
                        encryptedText, 0);*/
                if (senderinfo != null && timeStamp != 0
                        && msgString != null) {
                    System.out.println("entered into database");
                    outboxDatabase.open();
                    outboxDatabase.insertintoOutbox(base64msgString, key,
                            savedPhoneno, timeStamp);
                    outboxDatabase.close();
                }

                Intent homeScreenIntent = new Intent();
                homeScreenIntent.setClass(getApplicationContext(),
                        HomeScreen.class);
                startActivity(homeScreenIntent);
                finish();

                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }

    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    // short port = 8888;

    sms.sendTextMessage(edittextSmsNumber, null, msg,
            sentPI, deliveredPI);

    try {
        unregisterReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying what's happening - you're trying to unregister a new receiver that is not registered yet.

You should define your receivers as members of your class, replacing your dynamic instantiations. And after all call `unregisterReceiver` on each of your member receivers.

I think that it would fix it.